# Borrow Checker not releasing borrow from FnOnce callback

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Why does this compile:

```rust
fn func<T>(
  callback: impl FnOnce(&mut i64) -> T,
) -> T {
    let v = 42;
    callback(&mut 42)
}
```

but this not?:

```rust
fn func<'a, T>(
  callback: impl FnOnce(&'a mut i64) -> T,
) -> T {
    let v = 42;
    callback(&mut 42)
}
```

Even this doesn't compile:

```rust
fn func<'a, T: 'static>(
  callback: impl FnOnce(&'a mut i64) -> T,
) -> T {
    let v = 42;
    callback(&mut 42)
}
```

Is there a way to tell Rust that the `T` returned from the `callback` doesn't hold any references to `'a`? I thought `: 'static` would forbid references in general but it doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately, I do need to give `'a` a name because I'm using the lifetime elsewhere, the actual code is somewhat more complicated than this minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first snippet, the lifetimes are elided via [Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

```rust
fn func<T>(
  callback: impl for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i64) -> T,
) -> T {
    let v = 42;
    callback(&mut 42)
}
```

That means the closure can be called with any lifetime, and that includes the lifetime of `v`.

In your second snippet, the lifetime is chosen by the caller. This is not related to `T`: for example, the caller can choose `'static`, then store the parameter in a `static`. There is just no way to satisfy this requirement with a variable defined in the function.